# Node.js (MERN) Serving static files and API's

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Im currently building a simple app using the MERN stack to learn. What Ive done so far:

1. -User Registration and Login (API)
2. -TODO List (API and Frontend with static files)

Ok, Everything works good and as expected, except for one thing.

I attempt to use my API's for any request, but at the same time I want my whole app to work rendering in a web browser (TODO list). So, the process I've followed is:

1. -Start node instance
2. -npm run build (To build react project files)

I did a research on how to use React build in node project and I did the following:

```
app.use(express.static('myproject/build'));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'myproject', 'index.html'));
});
```

Good! So when I go to http://localhost:4000, it renders my index file and it actually works with my Login API, but I have some API's that are only available for consuming data and not rendering UI.

So, my problem is that when running the app, if I go to: http://localhost:4000/api/users/getdata
I get an error saying: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory pointing the index.html

Ok, if I uncomment the code I posted before, then of course my app is not rendering UI, but my routes from API's work normally.

I know this might be setup/configuration process, but Im trying my best to understand this. If somebody could assist me with this problem please.

The hierarchy im working goes as follows:

- myproject (contains models, routes (API's), middlewares, index.js)

  - frontend (inside folder 'myproject') (build, src (Components))

Comment: Try changing to: `app.get('/',`

Comment: @MaxAlex Wow! It worked. Cant believe that single star character made a huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what @MaxAlex suggested. Changed the code from:

```
app.get('/*')
```

to

```
app.get('/')
```